# Show icon for correct option in table based on result from API Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, angular9

I have a html table where there are multiple questions and 4 options to each question. I want to show a tick icon for the correct option. I will be getting the correct option answer in an API. The problem is I am not getting the correct way to show the icon in front of the correct option based on the API value. I have tried the following code:

API Response: `{ans1: "2", ans2: "1", ans3: "3"}`

So if for first question 2 is the answer from then my tick should be visible in front of the 2nd option.

HTML Code:

```
<table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>Sr. No</th>
            <th>Question</th>
            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>What type of investment is it?</td>
        
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td><ion-icon name="checkmark-outline" *ngIf="showOption"></ion-icon>normal</td>
        
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td><ion-icon name="checkmark-outline" *ngIf="showOption"></ion-icon>semi normal</td>           
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c</td>
            <td><ion-icon name="checkmark-outline" *ngIf="showOption"></ion-icon>semi hard</td>         
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>d</td>
            <td><ion-icon name="checkmark-outline" *ngIf="showOption"></ion-icon>hard</td>          
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>How investment is it?</td>
        
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td><ion-icon name="checkmark-outline" *ngIf="showOption"></ion-icon>normal</td>
        
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td><ion-icon name="checkmark-outline" *ngIf="showOption"></ion-icon>semi normal</td>           
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c</td>
            <td><ion-icon name="checkmark-outline" *ngIf="showOption"></ion-icon>semi hard</td>         
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>d</td>
            <td><ion-icon name="checkmark-outline" *ngIf="showOption"></ion-icon>hard</td>          
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Why investment is it?</td>
        
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td><ion-icon name="checkmark-outline" *ngIf="showOption"></ion-icon>normal</td>        
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>b</td>
            <td><ion-icon name="checkmark-outline" *ngIf="showOption"></ion-icon>semi normal</td>           
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>c</td>
            <td><ion-icon name="checkmark-outline" *ngIf="showOption"></ion-icon>semi hard</td>         
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>d</td>
            <td><ion-icon name="checkmark-outline" *ngIf="showOption"></ion-icon>hard</td>          
        </tr>
    </table>
```

TS Code:

```
showOption: boolean = false;
```

Comment: The problem is that all the answers have the same condition for the icon to appear. If showOption is true, it will be true for all. You need to modify the condition.

Comment: And you might need to change the way you show you get/show the quizz data : https://www.joshmorony.com/create-a-data-driven-quiz-app-in-ionic-2-part-2/

Comment: @uKioops I need help in the condition, that's where I am stuck, dont know how to proceed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At its most basic, you want to follow @uKioops's advice and follow that guide.

A 2-second look at it suggest it will take you from your hard-coded question approach to setting you up to use a data-driven approach. E.g. being given a list of questions and using an `*ngFor` loop to display them.

E.g. given a list of questions:

```
[
    { 
        id: 1, 
        text: "What type of investment is it?", 
        options: [
            { id: 1, text: "Some incorrect answer", isAnswer: false },
            { id: 2, text: "Correct answer", isAnswer: true },
            { id: 3, text: "Another incorrect", isAnswer: false }
        ]
    },
    { id: 2, ... },
    ...
]
```

You can then `*ngFor` over the questions, to give you a list of questions, and within that you can `*ngFor` over the list of options to show the options and optionally the check...

```
<ul *ngFor="let question of questions">
    <div>{{question.text}}</div>
    <li *ngFor="let option of question.options">
        <ion-icon name="checkmark-outline" *ngIf="option.isAnswer"></ion-icon> {{option.text}}
    </li>
</ul>
```